# istream& getline (istream& is, string& str); could be used for data which has '\n'?

Tags: c++

`istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);` here str terminates after newline character. But if I want to deal with situation where str cotents 2-3 lines then what is the alternative?

Comment: You wrap it in a `for` loop and run it 2 or 3 times.

Comment: @H2CO3: If I dont know how many times \n appears. Like I am processing content of articles!

Comment: Well... there must be **some** terminating condition. Like "read until the word `unicorn`", or something. Do you know of one?

Comment: @H2CO3: No there's not terminating condition. Process should terminate when all content in data structure finishes!

Comment: Well, as I stated, there ***MUST*** be some terminating condition. Here, it is that you have some sort of data structure. How do you know what/how many data to put into the data structure?

Answer (score 2):

You could give a message to tell the user to terminate input eg

```
std::cout<<"Enter your message (enter finish. to terminate input)"<<endl;
while (mess != "finish.")
{
   std::getline(std::cin, mess);
   input_message += mess;

}
```

Hope this helps as it is more dynamic

Answer (score 1):

I feel like we could use some sample input, but this code will read lines from `std::cin` until it can't find any more lines, and save all of those lines into a `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {    // iterates until exhaustion
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    // lines[k] can be used to fetch the k'th line read, starting from index 0

    // Simply repeat the lines back, prepended with a "-->"
    for (auto line : lines) {
        std::cout << "--> " << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

For example, if I input

```
cat
bat
dog
```

my program outputs

```
--> cat
--> bat
--> dog
```

Comment: Suppose `line` read the content from some text file then will it read till end of line? I manually tried it with giving some content in line like "abc xyz pqr" then after program run it does not terminate!

Comment: I added some sample input and output to my answer.

Comment: I ran it, but it keeps asking me to write new data. I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Use CTRL-Z or CTRL-D to signal the "end-of-file". To make the program more user-friendly, you could output a message to tell the user to type something to stop iteration.